# SQL Server stored procedure to insert/ update which has date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The source which has date in `dd-MMM-yy` format, have to convert it to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:SS` and insert/update into the database using stored procedure. New to stored procedure I managed to write a stored procedure but I don't where  or how to convert the date format.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdate]
    @dp             char(32),
    @dv             char(32),
    @e_num          char(12),
    @mail           varchar(50),
    @emerg          char(32),
    @opt1           char(16),
    @stat           char(20),
    @e_id           char(35),
    @e_tit          varchar(64),
    @e_date         datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE [dbo].[sampleemployee] AS [Target]
USING (SELECT @dp, @dv , @e_num, @mail, @emerg, @opt1, @stat, @e_id, @e_tit, @e_date)
AS [Source] ( dp, dv, e_num, mail, emerg, opt1, stat, e_id, e_tit, e_date)  
ON [Target].e_id = [Source].e_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN

UPDATE SET  dp               = [Source].dp,
            dv               = [Source].dv,
            e_num            = [Source].e_num,
            mail             = [Source].mail,
            emerg            = [Source].emerg,
            opt1             = [Source].opt1,
            stat             = [Source].stat,
            e_id             = [Source].e_id,
            e_tit            = [Source].e_tit,
            e_date           = [Source].e_date

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

INSERT ( dp, dv, e_num, mail, emerg, opt1, stat, e_id, e_tit, e_date)
VALUES ( [Source].dp, [Source].dv, [Source].e_num, [Source].mail, [Source].emerg, [Source].opt1, [Source].stat, [Source].e_id, [Source].e_tit, [Source].e_date);

END;
```

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server doesn't have any *format* associated with it - it's an 8-byte binary storage. The format only comes into play when you try to *display* the value (by converting it to a string) ...

Comment: @marc_s I am getting an error like "The input data for the field/parameter "e_date" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: The string '04-DEC-65' is not a valid AllXsd value.". I am new to Sql server or stored Procedure.

Comment: An explicit CAST should work.   I get no errors with this:   SELECT CAST( '04-DEC-65' AS datetime)

Answer (score 0):

it should be as simple as this..... Avoid using merge statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdate]
@dp             char(32),
@dv             char(32),
@e_num          char(12),
@mail           varchar(50),
@emerg          char(32),
@opt1           char(16),
@stat           char(20),
@e_id           char(35),
@e_tit          varchar(64),
@e_date         datetime
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[sampleemployee] WHERE e_id= @e_id)
  BEGIN
     UPDATE [dbo].[sampleemployee]
       SET  dp      = @dp,
            dv      = @dv,
            e_num   = @e_num,
            mail    = @mail,
            emerg   = @emerg,
            opt1    = @opt1,
            stat    = @stat,
            e_tit   = @e_tit,
            e_date  = @e_date
     WHERE  e_id    = @e_id
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[sampleemployee]( dp, dv, e_num, mail, emerg, opt1, stat, e_id, e_tit, e_date) 
     VALUES ( @dp, @dv, @e_num, @mail, @emerg, @opt1, @stat, @e_id, @e_tit, @e_date);
  END

END;
```

Comment: This was the error I was getting using the Merge > The input data for the field/parameter "e_date" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: The string '04-DEC-65' is not a valid AllXsd value. Does it go with the above stored procedure.

Comment: Why one should avoid using merge??

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri good question here is an article for you to read [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: @M.Ali in the above procedure where do I have to convert(varchar(50),@e_date,121)

Answer (score 0):

```
Just put this.. convert(varchar(50),@e_date,121) at your using select statement
```

.....

```
USING (SELECT @dp, @dv , @e_num, @mail, @emerg, @opt1, @stat, @e_id, @e_tit, convert(varchar(50),@e_date,121))
```

...

Comment: Thanks Prashant. If I am using @M.Ali's code with out Merge where do I convert(varchar(50),@e_date,121)